# How to extend a core Rails FormBuilder field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 with Rails 4, and I wanted to create a custom FormBuilder to handle some of Bootstrap's unique HTML syntax. Specifically, I needed a custom helper that would create the `form-group` div wrapper around a form field, since [Bootstrap applies error state to this wrapper, and not the field itself](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation)...

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="user_email">Email</label>
  <div class='col-md-9'>
    <input class="form-control required-input" id="user_email" name="user[email]" placeholder="peter@example.com" type="email" value="someone@example.com" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Note the extra class `has-error` in the outer div...

Anyway, I wrote that helper, and it works great!

```
def form_group(method, options={})
  class_def = 'form-group'
  class_def << ' has-error' unless @object.errors[method].blank?
  class_def << " #{options[:class]}" if options[:class].present?
  options[:class] = class_def
  @template.content_tag(:div, options) { yield }
end

# Here's a HAML sample...

= f.form_group :email do
  = f.label :email, nil, class: 'col-md-3 control-label'
  .col-md-9
    = f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control required-input', placeholder: t('sample.email')
```

Now I want to utilize Bootstrap's [form help text](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-help-text) in order to display error messages. This requires me to extend Rails native helpers (such as `text_field` in the example above) and then call them within the the block of `f.form_group`.

The solution **seemed** simple enough: call the parent, and append my span block onto the end...

```
def text_field(method, options={})
  @template.text_field(method, options)
  if !@object.errors[method].blank?
    @template.content_tag(:span, @object.errors.full_messages_for(method), class: 'help-block')
  end
end
```

Only it wouldn't output any HTML, the div would simply show up empty. I've tried a bunch of diff syntax approaches:

- `super` vs `text_field` vs `text_field_tag`
- `concat`-ing the results -- `@template.concat(@template.content_tag( [...] ))`
- dynamic vars, e.g. `def text_field(method, *args)` and then `options = args.extract_options!.symbolize_keys!`

I only ever get weird syntax errors, or an empty `div`. In some instances, the `input` field would appear, but the help text `span` wouldn't, or vice verse.

I'm sure I'm screwing up something simple, I just don't see it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Took a few days, but I ultimately stumbled onto the proper syntax. Hopefully it saves someone else's sanity!

Ruby's `return` automagic, combined with Rails at-times complex scoping, had me off kilter. Specifically, `@template.text_field` draws the content, but it must be returned by the helper method in order to appear inside the calling block. However we have to return the results of **two** calls...

```
def text_field(method, options={})
  field_errors = object.errors[method].join(', ') if !@object.errors[method].blank?
  content = super
  content << (@template.content_tag(:span, @object.errors.full_messages_for(method), class: 'help-block') if field_errors)
  return content
end
```

We must return the results of both the parent method (via `super`) plus our custom `@template.content_tag(:span,` injection. We can shorten this up a bit using Ruby's plus `+` operator, which concatenates return results.

```
def text_field(method, options={})
  field_errors = object.errors[method].join(', ') if !@object.errors[method].blank?
  super + (@template.content_tag(:span, @object.errors.full_messages_for(method), class: 'help-block') if field_errors)
end
```

**Note:** the form was initiated with an ActiveModel object, which is why we have access to `@object`. Implementing `form_for` without associating it with a model would require you to extend `text_field_tag` instead.

Here's my completed custom FormBuilder

```
class BootstrapFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder

  def form_group(method, options={})
    class_def = 'form-group'
    class_def << ' has-error' unless @object.errors[method].blank?
    class_def << " #{options[:class]}" if options[:class].present?
    options[:class] = class_def
    @template.content_tag(:div, options) { yield }
  end

  def text_field(method, options={})
    field_errors = object.errors[method].join(', ') if !@object.errors[method].blank?
    super + (@template.content_tag(:span, @object.errors.full_messages_for(method), class: 'help-block') if field_errors)
  end

end
```

Don't forget to tell `form_for`!

```
form_for(:user, :builder => BootstrapFormBuilder [, ...])
```

**Edit:** Here's a number of useful links that helped me along the road to enlightenment. Link-juice kudos to the authors!

- [Writing a custom FormBuilder in Rails 4.0.x](http://oldwildissue.wordpress.com/2013/11/13/writing-a-custom-formbuilder-in-rails-4-0-x/)
- [Formatting Rails Errors for Twitter Bootstrap](http://blog.michaelgreenly.com/2011/12/formatting-rails-errors-for-twitter.html)
- [Very Custom Form Builders in Rails](http://www.likeawritingdesk.com/posts/very-custom-form-builders-in-rails)
- [SO: Nesting content tags in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417097/nesting-content-tags-in-rails)
- [SO: Rails nested content_tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205613/rails-nested-content-tag)
- [SO: Rails 3 Custom FormBuilder Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607386/rails-3-custom-formbuilder-parameters)
- [SO: Trying to extend ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475526/trying-to-extend-actionviewhelpersformbuilder)
- [RailsGuides: Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)
- [Real world sample from treebook tutorial code](https://github.com/Soraph/treebook/blob/master/app/helpers/application_helper.rb#L26)